# SPARQL query is NULL by triples are visible

Tags: rdf, sparql

I'm using the data at http://agris.fao.org/aos/records/US19970166596, and sending it this query, but I get a null set of results:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/>
SELECT ?identifier ?title ?abstract
FROM NAMED <http://agris.fao.org/aos/records/US19970166596>
WHERE {
  ?identifier dc:identifier ?Identifier .
  ?title dc:title ?Title .
  ?abstract bibo:abstract ?Abstract .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://www.sparql.org/sparql?query=PREFIX%20dc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20bibo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fontology%2Fbibo%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fidentifier%20%3Ftitle%20%3Fabstract%0D%0AFROM%20NAMED%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fagris.fao.org%2Faos%2Frecords%2FUS19970166596%3E%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fidentifier%20dc%3Aidentifier%20%3FIdentifier%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Ftitle%20dc%3Atitle%20%3FTitle%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fabstract%20bibo%3Aabstract%20%3FAbstract%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl)

It occurred to me that SPARQL might not see this page as a graph. So I checked it using the Rhizomik service, to get [these results](http://rhizomik.net/redefer-services/rdf2html?rdf=http://agris.fao.org/aos/records/US19970166596&mode=html&namespaces=true&language=en).  Rhizomik properly processes the URI and generates RDFa. Also you can see information that is not exposed on the source page. Example: `j.3:creator` where a class is `foaf:Person` and a property is `foaf:name`.

Does the SPARQL query need to use, for example, `j.3:creator` rather than `dc:creator`?

How can I extract the value of the term `foaf:name`? Should I declare the `prefix foaf` and then query for a value (e.g. Finley J.W.)? Should I use an alternate method to process the content of the URI?

Comment: @Joshua TY for edits. How to mask the long SPARQL results URL with, as you did, "SPARQL results."

Comment: If you take a look at [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25389059/revisions), and view "side by side markdown", you can see the changes that I made.  Also see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)  In the editor, it's easiest to select the link text and press the editor button or Crtl-L, and paste the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM NAMED`  creates a name graph  (access with `GRAPH` in the query).

`FROM` loads the default graph, which is what you are querying.

Remove `NAMED`

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/>
SELECT ?identifier ?title ?abstract
FROM  <http://agris.fao.org/aos/records/US19970166596>
WHERE {
  ?identifier dc:identifier ?Identifier .
  ?title dc:title ?Title .
  ?abstract bibo:abstract ?Abstract .
}
```

and it works for me.

Comment: Do you get values for the variables? I only receive <http://agris.fao.org/aos/records/US19970166596> in the three fields. I was expecting to receive "| US19970166596 | Selenium content of foods purchased in North Dakota. | Selenium (Se) concentrations in foods are ... |"

Comment: Do you see values for the variables, or do you see the name of the URI as the value for all variables? My result returns the URI.